# Boundary conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I am kinda confuse with the second part of my homework. I did the first part (3/a and 4/a) without any problem, but part b for both problems I don't get it at all. I try to plug the boundaries in the u(x,t) equation, but for some reason i don't know what to do right after that. If somebody can help me I will be so thankfully. The problem is attached in a picture. [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- A Dirichlet condition is the prescription of  the values of the  solution  at the boundary. 
  A zero Dirichlet condition means the solution needs to be $0$ there. 
  So you are asked to find the $\theta$ so that for this choice of $\theta$, you have $u(0,t)= 0$ and $u(l,t)=0$. Practically speaking, you set $u(0,t)= 0$, with the function $u$ you have, and *solve* for $\theta$, same for $l$.
- A Neumann condition is the prescription of the derivative of the solution at the boundary.
  A zero Neumann condition means the derivative, with respect to $x$ in your case, of the solution needs to be $0$ there.
  So you are asked to find the $\theta$ so that for this choice of $\theta$, you have $u_x(0,t)= 0$ and $u_x(l,t)=0$.

Comment: for the first one would be cos(c*theta*t)=0 and then solve for theta, then I have that for values theta=pi/(2ct) u(x,t) satisfies the zero Dirichlet conditions. what about the second one? cos(c*theta*t)cos(l*theta)=0, I don't know how to solve that by hand.Thank you.

Comment: I am not sure why you say it is the cosine as the $u$ is an exponential term (that can be dropped as it is always nonzer, yes) but then a sine not a cosine. So solve $\sin( \theta 0)= 0$ and $\sin( \theta l)= 0$. The first yields no restriction, the latter does yield a restriction on the $\theta$. For the second problem, compute the derivative and then do the similar thing with the derivative. It is almost the same again you have a sin.

Comment: I'm taking about problem 4 part b. Sorry for not be that specific. I don't know if there is a way to attach a picture with my work here

Comment: Wait, I get it! thanks a lot. The second one is with the first derivative. Thanks a lot. is there a way to rate your answers?

Comment: Yes that's it. Then you have again a $\sin(\theta x)$ factor. For rating the answer: you can "accept" it, using the green check mark to the left, to mark the question as answered. In addition you can also vote on it, by pressing the upward or downward arrow to the left.